# Send Email error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel queues to get my mail working. My `SendMail` class is as such

```
class SendMail {
    public static function sendAbuseEmail($job,$data, $toEmail, 
    $subject, $fromEmail, $fromName) {
        Mail::send(array('html' => 'emails.abuseUrl.abuse'), 
                   $data, function ($m) use ($toEmail, $subject, 
                   $fromEmail, $fromName) {
            $m->from($fromEmail, $fromName);
            $m->to($toEmail)->subject($subject);
        });
        $job->delete();
    }
 }
```

and I am using it as such

```
$data = array('name' => Input::get('name'), 
              'quote' => Input::get('quote'), 
              'from' => Input::get('email'),
              'abuseUrl'=> Input::get('abuseUrl'));
$subject = Input::get('subject');
$toEmail = Config::get('settings.adminEmail');
$fromEmail = Input::get('email');
$fromName = Input::get('name');
Queue::push('SendMail@sendAbuseEmail', $data,$toEmail, 
           $subject, $fromEmail, $fromName);
```

but I am getting an error

> [2014-08-20 17:25:41] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Missing argument 3 for Codeforge\Mailers\SendMail::sendAbuseEmail(), called in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php on line 96 and defined' in /var/www/laravel/app/Codeforge/Mailers/SendMail.php:1

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you look what value `$toEmail` has?

Comment: @MarcB .. i replaced the toEmail with my email even then its not working. same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the method signature for [QueueInterface#push()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ef0864242e6e6f19a78f941b0710c844016ddf6e/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueInterface.php#L5-L13):

```
public function push($job, $data = '', $queue = null);
```

Where [`$data` can be anything that's `json_encode`able](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ef0864242e6e6f19a78f941b0710c844016ddf6e/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php#L44-L62). Instead of passing ordered arguments, convention is to pass an associative array:

```
Queue::push('SendMail@sendAbuseEmail', array(
    'data' => $data,
    'toEmail' => $toEmail,
    'subject' => $subject,
    'fromEmail' => $fromEmail,
    'fromName' => $fromName
));
```

And in your worker, you can access the values like:

```
public static function sendAbuseEmail($job, array $data)
{
    $toEmail = $data['toEmail'];
    // etc...
}
```

This is due to the fact that all drivers (with the exception of the `Sync` driver) need to serialize this data and write it to some kind of data-store for later reference.  I believe it was designed this way because it's just easier to keep track of if it's a single object.